# Essential singularity of a product $fg$

Tags: complex-analysis

I came across this question:

If $f:\mathbb{D}-\{0\}\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic where $z=0$ is an essential singularity of $f$ and $g:\mathbb{D}\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic then $fg:\mathbb{D}-\{0\}\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ preserves the essential singularity at $z=0$ ?

$g\not\equiv 0$

Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $g\colon \mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic and not identically $0$. Let $h\colon \mathbb{D}\setminus \{0\}\to \mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic with a removable singularity or a pole at $0$. Then we can write
$$g(z) = z^k\cdot g_1(z)\qquad\text{and}\qquad h(z) = z^m\cdot h_1(z)$$
with $g_1, h_1$ holomorphic on $\mathbb{D}$, $g_1(0) \neq 0$, $h_1(0) \neq 0$, and $k, m \in \mathbb{Z}$, $k \geqslant 0$. Hence
$$\frac{h(z)}{g(z)} = z^{m-k}\cdot \frac{h_1(z)}{g_1(z)}$$
has at worst a pole at $0$.

Thus $h$ cannot be of the form $f\cdot g$ where $f$ has an essential singularity at $0$.

We see that multiplication with a holomorphic function that doesn't vanish identically (on the connected component containing the singularity) preserves essential singularities.

Comment: +1. This is the way to go. Assume $fg$ has a removable singularity or a pole (i.e. not an essential singularity) and look at $\frac{fg}{g}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$f(z)=\sum_{k=-\infty }^\infty a_k z^k$$
$$g(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_nz^n$$

What is $fg$ ?

Comment: The problem is how to prove that there are infinitely many non-zero coefficients of the principal part of $fg$.

Comment: May be I didn't understand your question (and I apologize for this) but the question that I understood is "Is $z=0$ a singularity essential of $fg$" ? I want to precise that it's not because I answered that you have to put an upvote !! if you are not satisfied about my answer, don't upvote and ask question to understand more (or downvote if my answer is out of subject) :-)